# Proving every element of a sequence defined by a recurrence relation is an integer

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations

Define the sequence $(a_n)_n$ as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0 &= 1 \\
a_1 &= 2 \\
(n+3)a_{n+2}&=(6n+9)a_{n+1}-na_n
\end{cases}
$$ for $n \ge 0$

I am trying to prove that all terms of the sequence are integers. I have proved this using generating functions but it is long and messy. I want to know if there is a simpler proof that just uses elementary number theory. Perhaps an induction argument is possible?

Comment: Just for your curiosity, these are the large Schroeder numbers

Comment: Did you find the generating function ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks for that - I didn't know they had a name. Yes, I found the generating function.

Comment: In fact, they are also related to Gegenbauer polynomials. Congratulations for th g.f.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am now trying to derive the recurrence relation above from the definition in terms of lattice paths. I'm struggling with it though.

Comment: In the page of $OEIS$, sequence $A006318$, in the commenst section, they  write that $a_n$ *is the number of lattice paths...*

Comment: The recursion implies that $a_n$ is a multiple of $a_1$ if $n>0$. The problem is how to prove that it is an **integer** multiple.

Answer (score 1):

According to $OEIS$ (have a look [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+6%2C+22%2C+90%2C+394%2C+1806&sort=&language=&go=Search))
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} \binom{n+k}{n}$$

Comment: Your summation formula is the row sums of [OEIS sequence A088617](https://oeis.org/A088617) and this fact is mentioned in both $A088617$ and $A006318$. I am Still wondering how to connect this with the recurrence definition.

Answer (score 1):

Robert A. Sulanke, [*Bijective Recurrences concerning Schröder Paths*](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v5i1r47), shows that if $r_n$ is the number of lattice paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 2n,0\rangle$ using only up-steps $\langle 1,1\rangle$, down-steps $\langle 1,-1\rangle$, and double flat-steps $\langle 2,0\rangle$ and remaining strictly above the $x$-axis except at their endpoints, then these numbers satisfy the recurrence

$$(n+1)r_{n+1}=3(2n-1)r_n-(n-2)r_{n-1}$$

for $n\ge 2$, with $r_1=1$ and $r_2=2$. This is your recurrence with the indexing offset by $1$, so this is a combinatorial proof that your $a_n$ are integers. The bijection used to prove the result is more than a bit complicated, but it is described fairly clearly.